# Unity2d The character does not shoot to the left

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm making a game similar to soul knight. Weapon and character control is implemented by one joystick, as in the reference. I met a problem: if the character looks to the right, shooting works as it should, and if you turn to the left, then

1. shotPoint (the place of departure of bullets from the weapon) does not flip like a weapon, i.e. the weapon on the left seems to be turned upside down, although this is not the case
2. Bullets do not fly, but are created on the scene, apparently, they break on something

Code
Player.cs

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Joystick joystick;
    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 moveInput;
    private Vector2 moveVelocity;
    private Animator anim;

    private bool facingRight = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent < Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        moveInput = new Vector2(joystick.Horizontal, joystick.Vertical);
        moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;

        if (moveInput.x == 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        }

        if(!facingRight && moveInput.x > 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if(facingRight && moveInput.x < 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    public void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
    }
}
```

Gun.cs

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Joystick joystick;
    public float offset;

    public float rotZ;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRender;
    public GameObject bullet;
    public Transform shotPoint;
    private float timeBtwShots;
    public float startTimeBtwShots;
    private Player player;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        spriteRender = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Player>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Mathf.Abs(joystick.Horizontal) > 0.001f || Mathf.Abs(joystick.Vertical) > 0.001f)
        {
            rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(joystick.Vertical, joystick.Horizontal) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        }

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ + offset);

        if (rotZ < 90 && rotZ > -90)
        {
            spriteRender.flipY = false;
        }
        else
        {
            spriteRender.flipY = true;

        }


      //  if (timeBtwShots <= 0)
      //  {
        //    if (joystick.Horizontal != 0 || joystick.Vertical != 0)
        //    {
        //        ShootButton();
        //    }
      //  }
      //  else
      //  {
            timeBtwShots -= Time.deltaTime;
       // }
    }

    public void ShootButton()
    {
        Instantiate(bullet, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);
        timeBtwShots = startTimeBtwShots;
    }
}
```

Bullet.cs

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float lifetime;
    public float distance;
    public int damage;
    public LayerMask whatIsSolid;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right, distance, whatIsSolid);
        if (hitInfo.collider != null)
        {
            if (hitInfo.collider.CompareTag("Enemy"))
            {
                hitInfo.collider.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(damage);
            }
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.
For some reason, the bullet flies right after the launch, but not from a weapon

I tried to debug using Debug.Log, but came to nothing

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `Vector2.right` in here to shoot to left;

```
transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Wherever you shoot, bullet goes in Vector2.right direction. If you're looking left, then you need to pass `Vector2.left`.

```
    public void ShootButton(Vector3 direction)
        {
            Bullet bullet = Instantiate(bullet, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation).GetComponent<Bullet>();
            bullet.direction = direction;
            timeBtwShots = startTimeBtwShots;
        }
```

Create `public Vector3 direction;` in `Bullet.cs` and update line as;

```
transform.Translate(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

And in `Gun.cs`;

```
  if (timeBtwShots <= 0)
  {
       if (joystick.Horizontal != 0 || joystick.Vertical != 0)
       {
           Vector3 direction;
           if (facingRight)
               direction = Vector2.right;
           else if (facingLeft)
               direction = Vector2.left;

           ShootButton(direction);
       }
   }
   else
   {
        timeBtwShots -= Time.deltaTime;
   }
```

Something like this. You can improve the algorithm.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252992/discussion-on-answer-by-msaiduraz-unity2d-the-character-does-not-shoot-to-the-le); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.